# finding if a function has positive values in a given range

Tags: calculus, factoring

Context:trying to find a NEW fast way to factorize very big numbers using binary search

So I have a function:

$f\left(x\right)=\left(\cos\left(\pi x\right)^2+\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{x}\right)^2\right)^k-1.99^k$

when this function is greater than 0 , x is a factor of n.(most of the times, depends on how big k is)
Originally the 1.99 part is replaced with 2 and the function will be 0 only when x is factor of n, but there isn't much I can do with that.

So I recently thought about changing it slightly so the function will be positive when x is a factor of n, so that after using a "if x<0, f(x)=0" function i could calculate the integral of the function between two points, if it is higher than 0 that means a factor is in range and so I could cut the range in half and iterate this until I find x.
however, when I do try to this as shown here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6badnevuyv

when n=14, a & b (the range) is 4-8, the function(integral that uses f4) returns 0 although it should return a greater number

why isn't it working and is there a better way to actually check if a function is positive within a given range? or perhaps if n have factors in a given range

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but it is likely that you've exceeded Desmos's ability to calculate integrals accurately. Your method appears to have very low computational stability.

I would recommend a simpler approach. How about just using Newton's method to find roots of $$\cos\left(\pi x\right)^2+\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{x}\right)^2-2?$$

Though for that idea, it would be much better to find a curve that crosses $0$ at a slope near $\pm1$ than one that comes in tangent.

Comment: Newton's method might find obvious values such as (-1,1,-n,n) so I cannot use it

Comment: You can use it. You just have to be smart about using it instead of blindly letting it go wherever it wants. You might want to read up on Brent's method (which uses the inverse quadratic and secant methods instead of Newton's method, but that is because most applications don't have a calculable derivative).